# Fonts and mobile problems for new site

Tags: css, mobile

Hey guys I'm new to CSS and fonts but I'm having a basic problem where I can't change the size of my header default at all? When I change that from 1.5 em to 3em it has no effect.

```
h2 {font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif; font-size: 1.5em; color:#E7AE22; 
    line-height:26px; padding: 5px 0px 10px 0px;}
```

And also my title appears to be overlapping on mobile
http://i64.tinypic.com/28m3hb5.jpg

Don't know how to resolve this/what's causing this?

Comment: your css is working alright for me, playing with the font-size also working.  

https://jsfiddle.net/michabeeri/n58d61vy/

Answer (score 1):

you may want to try with `!important`

```
h2{
  font-size: 3em!important;
}
```

there is big chance that other css is overriting ur css you should inspect element and check

I sugest you to learn about Specifics on CSS Specificity https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/ this will help you alot

Answer (score 1):

You can give !important to h2 font-size. Or the best way is you can assign a class to H2 tag and then give font-size.

Giving !important to h2 tag will affect all h2 tags in your pages.

Give font-size this way:

```
h2.class-name {
   font-size: 3em;
}
```

will effect only that particular H2. Hope this helps.